# How to find the post having highest upvote without any downvote

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer

By this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/edit/506223)  I can able to get the highest number of post score *(the number of upvotes - number of downvotes)* for question, answer wise.

```
SELECT P.Id AS [Post Link], R.MaxScore, R.PostType
FROM Posts P
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT MAX(PO.Score) AS MaxScore, PT.Name AS PostType
    FROM Posts PO
    INNER JOIN PostTypes PT ON PT.Id = PO.PostTypeId 
          AND PT.Id IN (1, 2) -- 1 => Question, 2 => Answer
    WHERE PO.DeletionDate IS NULL 
    GROUP BY PT.Name
    ) R ON R.MaxScore = P.Score;
```

In the same way, is there possible to get the posts those having the highest number of upvotes, but never had a downvote?

Comment: The query doesn't tell you how many upvotes a post got. It tells you the post *score* (which is the number of upvotes - number of downvotes). As far as I know, SEDE doesn't contain a breakdown of upvotes/downvotes anywhere.

Comment: It does in the votes table @Oded

Comment: @rene - didn't remember if we had that... but the rest of my comment stands ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/506230) does show the posts that have no down votes, with the highest scoring (most upvotes) at the top.

```sql
select top 1000 p.id as [Post Link]
      , posttypeid 
      ,score 
from posts p
left outer join votes v on v.postid = p.id and votetypeid =3
where p.score > -1
and posttypeid in (1,2)
and v.id is null
order by score desc
```

The downvotes per post are stored in the [votes table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) as votetypeid = 3 (down mod)

Comment: This is exactly the same I want. Thanks.